# MPU-6050 changing X and Z axis values when only one axis is moved

Tags: arduino, mpu6050

I am building a drone and using an Arduino Uno to mostly control it. However, when I tilt the drone to test it, for example on the X axis, the program says it's been tilted on both the X and Z axis. I am using an MPU6050 gyroscope. Here is the code I am using:

```
//Written by Ahmet Burkay KIRNIK
//Measurement of Angle with MPU-6050(GY-521)

#include<Wire.h>

const int MPU_addr=0x68; int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;

int minVal=265; int maxVal=402;

double x; double y; double z;

void setup(){ Wire.begin(); Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); Wire.write(0x6B); Wire.write(0); Wire.endTransmission(true); Serial.begin(9600); } void loop(){ Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr); Wire.write(0x3B); Wire.endTransmission(false); Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true); AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read(); int xAng = map(AcX,minVal,maxVal,-90,90); int yAng = map(AcY,minVal,maxVal,-90,90); int zAng = map(AcZ,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);

x= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -zAng)+PI); y= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-xAng, -zAng)+PI); z= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -xAng)+PI);

Serial.print("AngleX= "); Serial.println(x);

Serial.print("AngleY= "); Serial.println(y);

Serial.print("AngleZ= "); Serial.println(z); delay(400); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gyroscope was bad, but the new one is still off but works. Anyways, it was the gyroscope.

Answer (score 0):

no human movement is perfect to just one axis you probably are moving in the other axis.
if it was me to make sure I would hold the chip/board/drone to an edge of a table or the like of it and tilt it over a bit and see if I see only movement in one axis.
you should only see negligible movement and the other axis
if it still shows unexpected significant movement
it is possible your chip is bad
I once had a cheap Chinese flight controller that used mpu6050 on-board sent to me broken but for me the problem was **no** movement in one axis
but I guess it is possible

Comment: No, both axis change about the same amount, even when it's obvious one is tilted a lot more. Also, I'll probably just get a new chip to test it.

Comment: maybe try the example code from here to see if it's not a hardware problem
https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050

Comment: No, that code does the same thing. The new one will arrive tomorrow, and then I'll see.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the new chip fixed that problem, but now the z axis is like 90 degrees off, but I just programmed around it and it kind of works. I still have a problem, but it's not related to the gyroscope.

Comment: well the hardware decides what orientation is "down" so usually you need to correct for the right orientation and direction.
anyways glad to hear!